# Raw query to add/alter column of table using Entity Framework without migration

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have restricted access to SQL server database & I have to alter table from my MVC project. I have tried:

```
var db = MyDbContext.Create();
try
{
    var res =
    db.Speakers.SqlQuery("ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Speakers] ADD [LastName] [nvarchar](256) NULL");
}
catch (Exception exception)
{
    Console.WriteLine(exception);
}
```

its not throwing exception but not updating table. I have no idea whether Raw query allow alteration or not. But I just gave a try. Can any one tell how can I alter database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach:

```
    db.Database
.ExecuteSqlCommand("ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Speakers] ADD [LastName] [nvarchar](256) NULL");
```

Answer (score 1):

> Non-query commands can be sent to the database using the
>   **ExecuteSqlCommand** method on Database. For example:
>
> ```
> using (var context = new BloggingContext()) 
> { 
>     context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand( 
>         "UPDATE dbo.Blogs SET Name = 'Another Name' WHERE BlogId = 1"); 
> }
> ```
>
> Note that any changes made to data in the database using
>   ExecuteSqlCommand are opaque to the context until entities are loaded
>   or reloaded from the database.

Entity Framework Raw SQL Queries
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj592907.aspx